# Getting a sequence like [(list[n-1], list[n+1]), (list[n-2], list[n+2]), ...]

Tags: python

I have tried below code

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
def fun(num):
    if num in list1:
        print(list1[num-2::-1],list1[num+1::1])

fun(9)
```

The output is `[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20`]

But the required sequence is like `[8, 10] [7, 11] [6, 12] [5, 13] [4, 14] [3, 15] [2, 16] [1, 17]`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain what exactly is the input and what is the expected output and how you get it?

Comment: Please add the full expected output. What happens with the remaining second numbers when the first number reaches 1? `[8,11],  [7,12],  [6,13],  [5,14],  [4,15],  [3,16],  [2,17],  [1,18],  [?,19],  [?,20]`.

Comment: Your pattern won't work. Look at @Jolbas's comment.

Comment: @SaiPrasadGudari Whats the expected output for e.g. `fun(19)` and `fun(20)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this;

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

res = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    res.append([list1[len(list1) - 1 - i], list1[i]])
print(res)
```

output:

```
[[20, 1], [19, 2], [18, 3], [17, 4], [16, 5], [15, 6], [14, 7], [13, 8], [12, 9], [11, 10], [10, 11], [9, 12], [8, 13], [7, 14], [6, 15], [5, 16], [4, 17], [3, 18], [2, 19], [1, 20]]
```

Comment: the output supposed to be like [[8, 10], [7, 11], [7, 12] and so on

Comment: what kind of pattern do you want. I mean does it has any special name ? If no, then please post the whole expected output as i am not getting you.

Comment: [(8, 10), (7, 11), (6, 12), (5, 13), (4, 14), (3, 15), (2, 16), (1, 17)]

Comment: @SaiPrasadGudari Then please edit your question with the full expected output. Becaause the question says first item should be `[8, 11]` instead of `[8, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

You could just [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the list slices you already have created. `zip()` groups the items from passed iterables by their indexes. But the output groups are tuples and that may not be what you want.

Also the `if` block is not necessary if you can accept an empty line to be printed if no items are found or `num` is out of range

```py
def fun(num):
    print(*zip(list1[num-2::-1], list1[num::1]))
fun(5)
# (4, 6) (3, 7) (2, 8) (1, 9)
```

You can also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions) to get what you want.

```py
def fun(num):
    n = min(num-1,len(list1)-num)
    print([[list1[num-i-2], list1[i+num]] for i in range(n)])
fun(16)
# [[15, 17], [14, 18], [13, 19], [12, 20]]
fun(25)
# []
```

Both functions will skip remainig items if it reaches an end of `list1`

Comment: why second number is going for only 17 leaving 18,19,20 the output is [(8, 10), (7, 11), (6, 12), (5, 13), (4, 14), (3, 15), (2, 16), (1, 17)]

Comment: @SaiPrasadGudari Do you mean the input list goes from 1 to 17?  What is  your expected output then?

Comment: @SaiPrasadGudari Edited second function so the second item always comes from index i+num+2 in list1

Answer (score 0):

You pattern is like `[8,11],  [7,12],  [6,13],  [5,14],  [4,15],  [3,16],  [2,17],  [1,18],  [?,19],  [?,20]`

So, it will give us error

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

res = []
num = int(len(list1)/2)
for i in range(num):
    res.append([list1[num-1 -i], list1[num + i]])
print(res)
```

Here what I have tried.

Output :

```
[[10, 11], [9, 12], [8, 13], [7, 14], [6, 15], [5, 16], [4, 17], [3, 18], [2, 19], [1, 20]]
```

I have tried something else by looking at your pattern also.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

res = []
num = int(len(list1)/2)
try:
    for i in range(num):
        res.append([list1[num-1 -i], list1[num -1-1+ i]])
except:
    print("Error")
print(res)
```

Output :

```
[[10, 9], [9, 10], [8, 11], [7, 12], [6, 13], [5, 14], [4, 15], [3, 16], [2, 17], [1, 18]]
```

The pattern little bit looking like your pattern.

Here `[10, 9], [9, 10]` might not be available in your pattern. For what,

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

res = []
num = int(len(list1)/2)
try:
    for i in range(num):
        res.append([list1[num-1 -i], list1[num -1-1+ i]])
    del res[0]
    del res[0]
except:
    print("Error")
print(res)
```

`del res[0]` removing first index.